# Creating dependent extjs grids

Tags: javascript, django, user-interface, extjs

I just started to study extjs 6.
How it is possible to implement dependent grids when the main displays data from the table, when clicked on, in the second grid, the dependent entries from the second table are displayed.

What I realized at the moment:
I created a grid, I get the records from the "Operation" table, I call it using the CRUD. In the "Operation" table, all entries are associated with the second table (numoperation) in the code field.

It is required to me that at pressing on record of the main grid which is already created, to receive dependent records from the table numoperation in the second grid.

How can this be implemented in general?
I would be glad if you share useful links, tips or examples.
Thank you in advance.

Below is the code for the client part of the application:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

Ext.define('Operation', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        'date_op',
        'code',
        'status',
        'type'
    ]
});

var urlRoot = 'data?model=Operation&method=';

var registrStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Operation',
    pageSize: 10,
    proxy: {
         type: 'jsonp',
        noCache: false,
        api: {
            create:     urlRoot + 'Create',
            read:       urlRoot + 'Read',
            update:     urlRoot + 'Update',
            destroy:    urlRoot + 'Destroy'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            metaProperty: 'meta',
            root: 'data',
            idProperty: 'id',
            totalProperty: 'meta.total',
            successProperty: 'meta.success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            encode: true,
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data',
            allowSingle: false,
        }
    }
});


var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 2,
    autoCancel: false,
    listeners: {
        edit: function (editor, context) {
            var emp = registrStore.getProxy();
            var con = context.record;
            emp.setExtraParam("id",                     con.data['id']);
            emp.setExtraParam("date_operation",         con.data['date_operation']);
            emp.setExtraParam("code",                   con.data['code']);
            emp.setExtraParam("status",                 con.data['status']);
            emp.setExtraParam("type",                   con.data['type']);               
        }
    }
});

var textField = {
    xtype: 'textfield'

};

// Определение столбцов
var columns = [
    {
        header: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'id',
        sortable: true,
        width: 35
    },
    {

        header: 'Дата',
        dataIndex: 'date_op',
        sortable: true,
        editor: textField

    },
    {
         header: 'Код',
         dataIndex: 'code',
         sortable: true,
         editor: textField
    },
    {
        header: 'Статус',
        dataIndex: 'status',
        sortable: true,
        editor: textField
    },
    {
        header: 'Тип',
        dataIndex: 'type',
        sortable: true,
        editor: textField
    }
];
  var pagingToolbar = {
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    store: registrStore,
    displayInfo: true,
    items: [
        '-',
        {
            text: 'Save Changes',
            handler: function () {
            registrStore.sync();
            }
        },
        '-',
        {
            text: 'Reject Changes',
            handler: function () {
                // Отмена изменений в stoe
                registrStore.rejectChanges();
            }
        },
        '-'
    ]
};

var onDelete = function () {
    var selected = grid.selModel.getSelection();
    Ext.MessageBox.confirm(
            'Confirm delete',
            'Are you sure?',
            function (btn) {
                if (btn == 'yes') {
                    var nn = selected[0].get('id')
                    var emp = registrStore.getProxy();
                    emp.setExtraParam("id", nn)
                    grid.store.remove(selected);
                    grid.store.sync();
                }
            }
    );
};


var onInsertRecord = function () {
    var selected = grid.selModel.getSelection();
    rowEditing.cancelEdit();
   var newEmployee = Ext.create("Operation");
   registrStore.insert(selected[0].index, newEmployee);
   rowEditing.startEdit(selected[0].index, 0);

};

var doRowCtxMenu = function (view, record, item, index, e) {
    e.stopEvent();
    if (!grid.rowCtxMenu) {
        grid.rowCtxMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Insert Operation',
                    handler: onInsertRecord

                },
                {
                    text: 'Delete Operation',
                    handler: onDelete
                }
            ]
        });
    }
    grid.selModel.select(record);
    grid.rowCtxMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
};


var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Таблица операций',
    items: grid,
    columns: columns,
    store: registrStore,
    loadMask: true,
    bbar: pagingToolbar,
    plugins: [rowEditing],
    stripeRows: true,
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    listeners: {
        itemcontextmenu: doRowCtxMenu,
        destroy: function (thisGrid) {
            if (thisGrid.rowCtxMenu) {
                thisGrid.rowCtxMenu.destroy();
            }
        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()

});
registrStore.load();
```

});

Comment: Was my answer helpful or not?

Comment: Yes, your answer was helpful, but overall I still have problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is to add a listener on the main grid that listens for the event: **select**.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#event-select

```
listeners: {
    select: "onSelectMainGrid",
},
```

then you want to have a function called onSelectMainGrid or something similar

```
var onSelectMainGrid : function(grid, selectedItem) {
. . . 
}
```

and in this function, you want to get the store from the dependent grids and you want to call the .load() function on them. For your dependent grid's store's proxy, use the config **extraParams: {}** 
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.data.Connection.html#cfg-extraParams and bind the selection from the main grid to the extraParams of the dependent grids. Then call the method .load() on the dependent grid's store. The store of your dependent grid will look something like

```
var dependentGridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model: 'OperationDependent',
pageSize: 10,
proxy: {
     type: 'jsonp',
    noCache: false,
    extraParams: {          // <==THIS IS NEW
      valueFromMainGrid: '{selectedValueFromMainGrid}'
    }
    api: {
        create:     urlRoot + 'Create',
        read:       urlRoot + 'Read',
        update:     urlRoot + 'Update',
        destroy:    urlRoot + 'Destroy'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
     . . .
     . . .
});
```

I noticed that you have all the code in the same file. It is strongly advised that you separate your code into views, viewModels, and viewControllers.

One last thing, If you don't make use of a viewModel for databinding, alternatively in the onSelectMainGrid function, since you are passing the selectedItem parameter, you can just get the dependent grid, then get its store, then get its proxy, and then set the extraParams to the selectedItem passed as parameter to the function.

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me understand how to work with listeners

Answer (score 0):

I did so (shortened the code for better perception):

```
Ext.define('Operation', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        'date_operation',
        'code',
        'status',
        'type',
        'mesto_hraneniya',
        'contragent',
        'sum_operation',
        'rezerv',
        'cnt_doc',
        'stellag'
    ]
});

var urlRoot = 'data?model=Operation&method=';
// Хранилище для данных таблицы Registr
var registrStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Operation',
    pageSize: 10,
    proxy: {
         type: 'jsonp',
        noCache: false,
        api: {
            create:     urlRoot + 'Create',
            read:       urlRoot + 'Read',
            update:     urlRoot + 'Update',
            destroy:    urlRoot + 'Destroy'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            metaProperty: 'meta',
            root: 'data',
            idProperty: 'id',
            totalProperty: 'meta.total',
            successProperty: 'meta.success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            encode: true,
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data',
            allowSingle: false,
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('Tovary', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        'name',
        'code',
        'prise',
        'unit'
    ]
});

var urlRootTv = 'data?model=Tovary&method=';
var TovaryGridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Tovary',
    pageSize: 10,
    proxy: {
         type: 'jsonp',
        noCache: false,
        extraParams: {
        inclProps: '{code_tv}'
        },
        api: {
            create:     urlRootTv + 'Create',
            read:       urlRootTv + 'Read',
            update:     urlRootTv + 'Update',
            destroy:    urlRootTv + 'Destroy'
        },
       reader: {
            type: 'json',
            metaProperty: 'meta',
            root: 'data',
            idProperty: 'id',
            totalProperty: 'meta.total',
            successProperty: 'meta.success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            encode: true,
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data',
            allowSingle: false,
        }
    }
});

......
// Grid панель
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Таблица операций',
    items: grid,
    columns: columns,
    store: registrStore,
    loadMask: true,
    bbar: pagingToolbar,
    plugins: [rowEditing],
    stripeRows: true,
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    listeners: {
        itemcontextmenu: doRowCtxMenu,
        destroy: function (thisGrid) {
            if (thisGrid.rowCtxMenu) {
                thisGrid.rowCtxMenu.destroy();
            }
        },
        select: function(grid, selectedItem) {
        TovaryGridStore.proxy.extraParams = {'code_tv' : selectedItem.id.code};
             TovaryGridStore.load();


        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()

});
registrStore.load();
```

When I click on a row in the grid, the browser console displays an error:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello_extjs/data?model=Tovary&method=Read&code_tv=&page=1&start=0&limit=10&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback2 500 (Internal Server Error)

What is the cause of this error? Whether correctly I understand that now I need to deduce the second Ext.grid.Panel what to display in it the data of model "Tovary"?